# Why does firebase not recognize my firebase instance? "call Firebase App.intializeApp()"

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I have two files, an `App.js` where I set up my React Navigation StackNavigator along with my firebase instance and a `Login.js` where I login users.

I am trying to detect if a user has already logged in (thru firebase persistent login) but for some reason, my firebase instance is not being detected in `Login.js`'s `componentDidMount()`. This doesn't make sense to me because elsewhere in my `Login.js`, I call fxns on my firebase instance, like logging in with Google.

How should I arrange the firebase initialization/auth check to ensure the firebase instance is detected correctly along with the persistent auth check?

I have already looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993403/react-native-firebase-error-app-hasnt-been-created) but that person seems to have a different problem as they are only concerned with the firebase instance in a *single file*.

Relevant portions of `App.js`

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import Login from './components/login';

const Application = StackNavigator({
    Login: { screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Login',
        }
    },
    SignUp: { screen: SignUp,
        navigationOptions: {
           title: 'Signup',
         }
    },
    Home: { screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
           title: 'Home'
       }
    },
});

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "APIKEY",
    authDomain: "AUTH_DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "DATABASE_URL",
    projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
    storageBucket: "BUCKET",
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        //if no instance exists, initialize one
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Application/>
        );
    }
}
```

Relevant portion of `Login.js`

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import Home from './home';

export default class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isLoggingIn: true,
            authFlag: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //error is on the following line
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if(!this.state.authFlag){
                this.setState({ authFlag: true })
                //persistent success, take user to Home
                if(user){
                     this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
                     return;
                }

                //user hasn't logged in before, must log in
                else{
                     this.setState({isLoggingIn: false});
                     return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Child components mount before their parents. `componentDidMount` of your login component is happening before `componentDidMount` of your app..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814970/is-componentdidmount-of-parent-called-after-all-componentdidmount-of-children

Comment: I see. I'm having trouble understanding how this is compatible with the parent->child flow of data in React-Native. If a child's component is mounted before that of it's parent, is that not denying data initialized in a parent component the ability to flow to its child (as in my case)?

Comment: It depends on how you get your data. If you are fetching your data in `componentDidMount` then you should do it in the parent. Then the parent can trickle down the data to its children and the children would receive the data in `componentWillReceiveProps`. At least until React 17 that is...

Comment: Say there is a Navigator with `App.js` -> `Login.js` -> `Home.js`, this means that one would initialize their firebase instance in `Home.js`?? How would one refactor the code I have posted to initialize it in `App.js` and allow `Login.js`'s `componentDidMount()` to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments above child components mount before their parents. `componentDidMount` of your login component is happening before `componentDidMount` of your app. [Stack overflow question outlining the deets.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814970/is-componentdidmount-of-parent-called-after-all-componentdidmount-of-children)

Just doing a quick search, it looks like most people do `firebase.initializeApp` outside of their component. [Was just reading this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/).

Comment: Wow that is a great guide you linked at the end, thank you very much!